# How to get a value from $.something{(...)}

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.simpleWeather({
    location: coordinates,
    unit: 'c'
}
```

and I would like to get the value of 'unit'. How do I get it? I tried this:

```
console.log($.simpleWeather.unit);
```

But it returns 'undefined'.

Also, because I don't how to call this, I can't simply Google it either...

Comment: Post your complete code?, what is the variable `coordinates` pointing to?

Comment: what do you see when you do console.log($.simpleWeather). The output might help you find a way to access unit

Comment: You could just use an extra variable there - 
var params = {location: 'coordinates', unit: 'c'};
$.simpleWeather(params);
params.unit

Comment: It all depends on how the `simpleWeather` plugin has been constructed and what methods and properties it allows you to access. However there's no reason you couldn't store the value you provide to `unit` in your own variable and reference that where needed in your code

Comment: Look at this demo : http://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/xklfq
It could help :)

Comment: Storing the value for 'unit' does indeed seem the easiest and most logical solution for what I'm trying to do.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends entirely on what `simpleWeather` does with the object you put in there. by the looks of it, simpleWeather is a jquery extension. you can view those as a function that takes parameters, and may (or may not) return a jquery selector.

if simpleWeather returns a jquery itself rather than a bare jquery selector (or indeed nothing at all), you can do this :

```
var sw = $.simpleWeather({
    location: coordinates,
    unit: 'c'
}

console.log(sw.unit);
```

You might want to try doing this, just to figure out what is actually in the return value of the jquery extension.

```
var sw = $.simpleWeather({
    location: coordinates,
    unit: 'c'
}

console.log(sw);
```

if there is no way to retrieve the unit from the return value of the extension, you might want to keep separate track of it.
In case of multiple instances you could do this with an array, something like this :

```
  var swInstances = [];

  ...
  var swParameters = {
     unit : 'c',
     location : coordinates,
  };

  swInstances.push({
     usedParameters : swParameters,
     simpleWeatherInstance : $.simpleWeather(swParameters)
  });
```

you can then use the swInstances array to access all the information you'd need per simpleWeather instance.